# i got this error : Warning: call_user_func_array() expects exactly 2 parameters, 3 given in

Tags: php

```
<?php

class App {
    protected $controller = 'Home';
    protected $method = 'index';
    protected $params = [];

    public function __construct()
    {
        $url = $this->parseURL();

        // controller
        if(file_exists('../app/controllers/' . $url[0] . '.php') ) {
            $this->controller = $url[0];
            unset($url[0]);
        }

        require_once '../app/controllers/' . $this->controller . '.php';
        $this->controller = new $this->controller;

        // method
        if( isset($url[1]) ) {
            if( method_exists($this->controller, $url[1]) ) {
                $this->method = $url[1];
                unset($url[1]);
            }
        }

        //params
        if( !empty($url) ) {
            $this->params = array_values($url);
        }

        call_user_func_array($this->controller, $this->method, $this->params);



    }

    public function parseURL()
    {
        if( isset($_GET['url']) ) {
            $url = rtrim($_GET['url'], '/');
            $url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
            $url = explode('/', $url);
            return $url;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
call_user_func_array($this->controller, $this->method, $this->params);
```

This call is wrong, [check this example](https://www.php.net/call_user_func#example-6375) on the official PHP documentation. Your code should be the following instead: (using array syntax for class methods).

```
call_user_func_array([$this->controller, $this->method], $this->params);
//                   ^                                ^
```